# Solve "Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:]" in UITests

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

When I run UITests (XCUITests) on the simulator, often it produces the bug: "Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:]" I don't have an activity indicator in my code, so this makes me think it is an Xcode related issue.  Does anyone have a work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It usually goes away when I simply
1. run the app normally in the simulator
2. Try running my XCUITest again.

Comment: Is this meant to be an answer to your question or just further details? If this is not an answer to your own question, then please delete this and edit your question as needed.

Comment: It is an answer to my question.  That is what solves it for me.